# Why is it that all of my post requests for my server.js fails?

Tags: node.js, express, vite

I am new to nodejs, express, and vite. I am trying to learn how to configure nodejs and took on a challenge I found on glitch that uses vite.

I have this server.js code right below. I think everything is going okay but whenever I add a post end point and attempt at prodding the endpoint using postman or through my react app it keeps on responding with 404...

Here is the code:

```
// server.js

// init project
import express, { json, urlencoded } from 'express'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import { join } from 'path'
import { santaController } from './src/server/controllers/santa-controller.js'
import { apiConfig } from './config/api-config.js'
import { emailSender } from './src/server/services/email-sender.js'

// Starting up express
const app = express()

// Middleware
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.post('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello')
})

app.post(apiConfig.WISH_API.POST_WISH, async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { user, userAddress, wish } = request.body
    const wishId = await santaController.postWish(user, userAddress, wish)

    // Send the generated wish ID as a response
    response.send({ wishId })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Failed to post wish:', e)
    response.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to post wish' })
  }
})

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'))
  console.log(response.json(routes))
})

// listen for requests :)
const listener = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port)

  // Initialize the email sender
  emailSender.initEmailSender()
})
```

I am using a config file to store my api end points and it is defined here:

```
// Storing Fetch API URLs in a config file for maintainability
const BASE_PATH = `/api`
const API_VER = `/v1`

export const apiConfig = {
  WISH_API: {
    POST_WISH: `${BASE_PATH}${API_VER}/wish`,
  },
}
```

As for my react app I have this line here that calls the endpoint:

```
// Make a POST request to the wish endpoint
const response = await axios.post(apiConfig.WISH_API.POST_WISH, wishData, {
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', },});
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried setting up a simple post endpoint that just says hello yet hitting that with postman also fails

I've looked at the network tab too and it just says 404.
I can provide anything related to the request object if needed.

But for now here is the header and request URL:

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/wish
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
[::1]:3000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

```
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
ja-JP,ja;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Connection:
keep-alive
Content-Length:
174
Content-Type:
application/json
Dnt:
1
Host:
localhost:3000
Origin:
http://localhost:3000
Referer:
http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
cors
Sec-Fetch-Site:
same-origin
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Does your `app.get('/'` and `app.post('/api'` work?

Comment: I tried on Postman and it works. / returns my index.html as configured. Interestingly enough /api doesnt return what I want it to return. I have it send ```app.get('/api', (request, response) => {
  response.send('1')
})``` fully expecting on postman I'd see that "1" be returned but I get my index.html instead.